# Set the filename to date in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

So I have the idea of creating a logfile based on the date of the creation. I have to do this in batch. My code so far:

```
@echo off
>log.txt (
cd %~dp0
echo [%DATE%] [%TIME%] [%USERNAME%] : Test
)
pause
```

How can I do this?. If I set the filename to `%DATE%.log` I get an error. Can I do this with some kind of `SET filename=%DATE%`? But then I have to use `%filename%.log` and I doubt this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%DATE%` returns (e.g. Tue 08/18/2015), since we can't rename/set a file name with "/" character inside, so replace the forward slash with an empty character like:

```
set Valid_DATE=%DATE:/=%
```

Then you simple replace `[%DATE%]` with `[%Valid_DATE%]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't look for the format of the date......in my case it was 18.08.2015 which caused the problem. I fixed it with NEW_DATE=%DATE:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%